# Displaying additional tags from EC2 instances using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, boto3

I'm trying to pull additional data from my EC2 instances using boto3.  This includes env,region,tags, etc

Using the current code

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters = [{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running','stopped','terminated']}])
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type,)
```

The output is:

```
    i-xxxxxxxx m3.medium
    i-xxxxxxxx m3.medium
    i-xxxxxxxx m3.medium
```

etc

I see you can use Filters (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html) but confused on what keywords I can filter by and where to find them.

Comment: Does this (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) help?

Comment: See above, it is all listed under the `Filters` section.